# How do I divide the rows of a matrix by different values in MATLAB (array division)

Tags: matlab, matrix, rows, division

Lets said I have the matrix `M = ones(3);` and I want to divide each row by a different number, e.g., `C = [1;2;3];`.

```
1 1 1  -divide_by-> 1      1   1   1
1 1 1  -divide_by-> 2  =  0.5 0.5 0.5
1 1 1  -divide_by-> 3     0.3 0.3 0.3
```

How can I do this without using loops?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use right array division as documented [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/rdivide.html)

```
result = M./C
```

whereas C has the following form:

```
C = [ 1 1 1 ; 2 2 2 ; 3 3 3 ];
```

**EDIT:**

```
result = bsxfun(@rdivide, M, [1 2 3]'); % untested !
```

Comment: I went through that documentation before. Nevertheless, they explicitly said that both matrix should have the same dimension. Not this being the case.
I also was thinking: is it possible to expand the vector to a matrix of the same size to perform element by element division?

Comment: the first one is basically `M ./ repmat(C,1,3)`. An additional solution is: `M ./ (C*ones(1,3))`, though I prefer to use BSXFUN.