# Quick question about MATLAB elementwise division

Tags: matlab, matrix, division

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I divide the rows of a matrix by different values in MATLAB (array division)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939700/how-do-i-divide-the-rows-of-a-matrix-by-different-values-in-matlab-array-divisio)

I have a matrix A (size MxN) in Matlab and a Vector b with M rows and now I want to divide all elemtens in the i-th row of A by the i-th entry in b like `a(i,:)/b(i)` but I really don't want to use this sort since I than use a for-loop and I definitly need a FAST solution!
Could anybody help out? Thanks!

**Edit**: Somehow I just came up with it after posting... My solution is `bsxfun(@rdivide, [1 1; 2 2; 3 3], [2 2 6]')`, do you think that's a good and fast one?

Comment: Okay thanks, I thought it was quite hard to find :( But thanks for pointing to it

Comment: ...and the others duplicates/related questions: [How do I divide matrix elements by column sums in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1773099/52738), [How can I divide each row of a matrix by a fixed row?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4723824/52738), [how to divide matrix elements by sum of row](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5527945/52738), [How to subtract a vector from each row of a matrix?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5342857/52738), [Matlab - Quickly subtract 1xN array from MxN matrix elements](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5967940/52738)

Comment: I was just adding the others in a comment so they would appear in the Linked sidebar, making them easier to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use bsxfunc :

```
bsxfun(@rdivide,A,B)
```

http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/bsxfun.html

Comment: How is that different from the solution he asked about above ?

Comment: i had answered before said comment was put. Sorry.