# Matlab-Array Division with different dimensions

Tags: matlab

I use Matlab and I have two matrices, X and Y of different dimensions: `X=[X11 X21 X31;X12 X22 X32;X13 X23 X33]`  is of dimension 3*3. `Y=[Y1;Y2;Y3]` is a column vector of dimension 3*1. I want to divide each element in the rows of X by the element on the corresponding rows of Y. I wish to obtain the following matrix: `Z=[X11/Y1 X21/X11/Y1 X31/X11/Y1;X12/Y2 X22/Y2 X32/Y2;X13/Y3 X23/Y3 X33/Y3]`

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You should use the `bsxfun` solution from the duplicate rather than the accepted `repmat` solution. I'm looking for a better dup target.

Comment: how is this not a duplicate...surely this *must* be a duplicate

Comment: This one might be better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939700/how-do-i-divide-the-rows-of-a-matrix-by-different-values-in-matlab-array-divisi

Comment: I think bsxfun is adequate. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @GameOfThrows I found, like, 3 dozen dups... the problem is trying to pick one ;)

Comment: @beaker :D hardest choice we all face...Naming a variable and finding the better duplicate..